# JSON EXTRACT Search Key use LIKE

Tags: mysql, json-extract

So I got JSON and Choice column on MySQL (10.3.15-MariaDB-1:10.3.15+maria~bionic)

This is the JSON =

```
{"04:17":62,"05:16":31,"06:15":18,"07:14":12,"08:13":8,"09:12":7,"10:11":6}
```

And the choice is half of the key like 04 / 17 / 08 / 12 etc.

I already try this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"04:17":62,"05:16":31,"06:15":18,"07:14":12,"08:13":8,"09:12":7,"10:11":6}','$.08:13');
```

return 8, it's work fine but the value I have only 13...

So

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"04:17":62,"05:16":31,"06:15":18,"07:14":12,"08:13":8,"09:12":7,"10:11":6}','$.13');
```

then it will return null because key is not found.

Is there anyway to search key use like "LIKE"?
already try $.%13% or $%.13%
{"04:17":62,"05:16":31,"06:15":18,"07:14":12,"08:13":8,"09:12":7,"10:11":6} LIKE '%13%'

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: I use MySQL 10.3.15

Comment: No such version. Query `SELECT @@version;` and post complete answer.

Comment: 10.3.15-MariaDB-1:10.3.15+maria~bionic

Comment: In your DBMS version I see the only method. Use recursive CTE, parse your JSON to separate key-value pairs, test each pair against your condition, and return matched values.